# Obtain the field member of the class where the macro is defined in

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I'm trying to define a macro in a trait. For example,

```
trait Macro {
  val magic: Int = 1001
  def doMagic(x: Int): Int = macro Impl.doMagic
}

object Impl {
  def doMagic(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Int] = ???
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is, the doMagic implementation should be able to refer to the field `magic` in the trait `Macro`, type-safely.

I tried to refer to this by `This(c.enclosingClass.asModule.moduleClass)`, but it seems to refer the tree of macro application, which resulting an anonymous class called $iw. So in my understanding the Enclosures is where the macro is being applied, not where it's being defined.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it out. We should use c.prefix, like

```
val self = TermName(c.freshName("self"))

c.Expr[T] {
  q"""
    val $self = ${c.prefix.tree}
    ...
  """
}
```

And a self variable can be used to capture the prefix, so it's only evaluated once.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the question directly, but maybe it helps nonetheless. You could pass the instance as parameter to the macro and to hide this from the caller you could add a corresponding method delegating to `doMagic` like this:

```
trait Macro {
  val magic: Int = 1001
  def doMagic(m: Macro, x: Int): Int = macro Impl.doMagic
}

object Impl {
  def doMagic(context: Context)(m: context.Expr[Macro], x: context.Expr[Int]): context.Expr[Int] = {
    import context.universe._
    reify(m.splice.magic + x.splice)
  }
}
```

the wrapper-trait:

```
trait Macro2 extends Macro {
  def doMagic2(x: Int): Int = doMagic(this, x)
}
```

and the caller:

```
val z = new Macro2 {}
println(z.doMagic2(5))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Volker. This does work. But in my case, the parameter is a complicated DSL class and part of it cannot be evaluated unless inside the macro implementation. So it doesn't suit my specific use case.